# uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined magento 2

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I am getting this error on checkout page every time and checkout not working any idea how to solve it.
**uncaught type error cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined Magento 2**

Comment: Please provide more details like screenshot. have you added any module recently?

Comment: i have disable all the module that i have installed

Comment: have you run cache flush, di compile and static content deploy commands after that?

Comment: here is the error screenshot
https://prnt.sc/koochm
 i flush compile and deploy static content many time

Comment: any solution for this

Comment: Some one has added that text for translate i would suggest to find that in source or js files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82518/discussion-between-kunj-and-roshan-yadav).

Comment: Mean ??? Please explain